# Parent div automatically shifts when displaying child div

Tags: jquery, html, hide

Heres the html:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="showDiv"></div>
    <div id="filtersDiv">    
        <div id="hideDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div id="headlineDiv">Block 1</div>
        <div id="storyDiv">Block 2</div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Initially, showDiv is hidden, and in it's place filtersDiv is displayed. Later, when the userr clicks on hideDiv, filtersDiv becomes hidden and showDiv becomes visible. However, when this happens, mainDiv's height automatically increases to the height of "showDiv" + "contentDiv". What I want is for these to be displayed side by side.

Heres the script:

```
 $('#hideDiv').click(function () {
          $('#hideDiv, #filtersDiv').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function () {
              $('#showFDiv').show();
          });
      });
```

I'm fairly new to jquery, any comments would help. Thanks.

Comment: Are #filtersDiv and #contentDiv displayed side by side in the first place? Could you expand on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBv6f/) to demonstrate the effect?

Comment: how can the user click on the hidden div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for.

Let me ask you first that Have those Divs been shown side-by-side in the first place?

If not, you have to make them:

```
#showDiv, #contentDiv, #filtersDiv { float:left;}
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/sBv6f/2/

Comment: I realised my mistake, I had given a float:left to #contentDiv, but missed writing it on #showDiv, that was the only issue. Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to your markup what i have noticed is you haven't closed your mainDiv but again that's not a big issue , i am going to place the entire file here with html , css and js . Just try that and see if that can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
     <html lang="en">  
   <head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>Untitled</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $('#hideDiv').click(function () {
      $('#filtersDiv').hide(function () {
          $('#showDiv').show();
      });
  });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #showDiv{
        display: none;
    }
 </style>
     </head>
      <body>

<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="showDiv">Show div</div>
    <div id="filtersDiv"> Filter Div
        <div id="hideDiv">Hide Div</div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div id="headlineDiv">Block 1</div>
        <div id="storyDiv">Block 2</div>
    </div>
</div>

      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: @nnnnnn :- because it do works and there are some alterations

Comment: Which part makes showDiv and contentDiv display side-by-side?

Comment: which part says to display it side by side.. read question for better understanding :-(    try it here http://jsfiddle.net/qm6bR/

Comment: Which part? "What I want is for these to be displayed side by side."

Comment: end the argue.. and check the code of jsfiddle .. if you can help him by improving the code that's good.. otherwise leave the way it is... n no offense